# Can I send an order to multiple emails?

Tags: order-email

We run an online fishing lure store, there are several people involved in creating and sending out our products. I need to send a customers order from our store to multiple email addresses so an order can be processed. Is there a way I can do this? I know that you usually use a comma or semi-colon to separate multiple email addresses but it does not allow me to do this in Magento.

Can anyone please help with this.

Comment: In "Sales > Emails > Send Order Email Copy To" you can add a comma separated list of addresses. Please describe in detail what you tried and what happened. Screenshots might help. Also: which Magento version are you using?